# Ajax call to Controller 404'ing

Tags: magento2.3, controllers, ajax

I've created a controller within my custom module to add items to my basket and i'm trying to make an ajax call across to it. However, I can't even call my controller currently as I get a 404 error from my ajax call.

**This is how my Controller currently looks:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\TestModule\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Test extends Action
{

    public function __construct(
        Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return "Success";
    }
}
```

**This is the ajax call in my phtml file:**

```
var data = "";
var addToCartUrl = "<?php echo $block->getUrl('testmodule/index/test'); ?>";

$.ajax({
    url : addToCartUrl,
    dataType : 'json',
    type : 'POST',
    data: data,
    success : function(res)
    {
        console.log('Success');
    },
    error : function()
    {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

**Here is my routes.xml file:**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="admin">
    <route id="test_testmodule" frontName="test_testmodule">
        <module name="Test_TestModule" />
    </route>
</router>
```

I've tried to manually visit the URL that i'm sending the ajax call to and that doesn't display anything either.

Comment: how did you define the route for this controller?

Comment: @DianaBotean I will add it to the question 1 sec

Comment: please try `test_testmodule/index/test` in call url

Comment: shouldn't you use then 'test_testmodule' in the url (as this is your frontName)?

Comment: @DianaBotean I will give it a try, thankyou :)

Comment: oh and also, i think you should use the 'standard' router id and not 'admin' if you are working on the frontend side as per your url call

Comment: I am working on the frontend! I think that could be it

Comment: please try it out and let me know if it solves the problem so we could write a proper answer :)

Comment: Ok, so it is giving me a 500 error now. So the controller is being called now at least. Given what's in there though it's odd it would error. I've checked the logs and it's because of an invalid return type. Given the question though i'd say your answer has fixed the problem :) I would be happy to upvote your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119628/discussion-between-diana-botean-and-a-fletcher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed, i see that a few corrections are needed:

1. you should call the 'test_testmodule/index/test' url as you defined your frontName as 'test_testmodule'
2. you should use the 'standard' routerId if you are working on the frontend side with this call
3. you are expecting a JSON formatted response as per your AJAX call definition, so you will have to format it serverside by injecting `Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory` into a protected property (say $resultJsonFactory) inside your controller class and using it like so:

```php
$result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
return $result->setData(['success' => true]);
```